# change content body background color in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, background

I have a wordpress website its http://pacelinegroup.com/ as you see below the slideshow theres a body which is the main content of the site. I want it to be all black instead of white. I tried changing it but it doesnt make it white the entire area. Please help me on what css code to use to make it entirely black everything.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
body#home #main-content {
    background: url("images/main_content_bg.png") repeat-y 480px 39px #000000;
}
```

style.css (line 136)

```
body#home #recent-posts {
    background: url("images/rec_posts_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 2px 0 #000000;
    width: 480px;
}
```

style.css (line 141)

```
body#home #sidebar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 480px;
}
```

style.css (line 342)